# Show counts of all date according to another table in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, One is calendar and second is final_registration as follow:

My Calendar table:

```
*--------------------*
| S.No. |  datefield |
*--------------------*
|  1    | 2019-01-01 |
|  2    | 2019-01-02 |
|  3    | 2019-01-03 |
|  4    | 2019-01-04 |
|  5    | 2019-01-05 |
|  6    | 2019-01-06 |
|  7    | 2019-01-07 |
|  8    | 2019-01-08 |
|  9    | 2019-01-09 |
|  10   | 2019-01-10 |
|  11   | 2019-01-11 |
|  12   | 2019-01-12 |
|  13   | 2019-01-13 |
|  14   | 2019-01-14 |
|  15   | 2019-01-15 |
|  16   | 2019-01-16 |
|  17   | 2019-01-17 |
|  18   | 2019-01-18 |
|  19   | 2019-01-19 |
|  20   | 2019-01-20 |
|  21   | 2019-01-21 |
|  22   | 2019-01-22 |
|  23   | 2019-01-23 |
|  24   | 2019-01-24 |
|  25   | 2019-01-25 |
|  26   | 2019-01-26 |
|  27   | 2019-01-27 |
|  28   | 2019-01-28 |
|  29   | 2019-01-29 |
|  30   | 2019-01-30 |
|  31   | 2019-01-31 |
---------------------
```

My Second table:

```
*-----------------------------------------*
| id | event_id |  name |    booking_date  |
*-----------------------------------------*
| 1  |   101    |  Ritu | 2019-01-15 13:21 |
| 2  |   101    | Seeta | 2019-01-15 18:21 |
| 3  |   101    | Geeta | 2019-01-16 13:21 |
| 4  |   102    | Wasim | 2019-01-16 14:21 |
| 5  |   102    | Rahul | 2019-01-17 13:21 |
| 6  |   101    | Gagan | 2019-01-17 14:21 |
| 7  |   101    | Sunny | 2019-01-17 15:21 |
| 8  |   101    | Aman  | 2019-01-17 16:21 |
-------------------------------------------
```

I am trying below output:

```
*--------------------*
|  datefield | count |
*--------------------*
| 2019-01-01 |  0   |
| 2019-01-02 |  0   |
| 2019-01-03 |  0   |
| 2019-01-04 |  0   |
| 2019-01-05 |  0   |
| 2019-01-06 |  0   |
| 2019-01-07 |  0   |
| 2019-01-08 |  0   |
| 2019-01-09 |  0   |
| 2019-01-10 |  0   |
| 2019-01-11 |  0   |
| 2019-01-12 |  0   |
| 2019-01-13 |  0   |
| 2019-01-14 |  0   |
| 2019-01-15 |  2   |
| 2019-01-16 |  1   |
| 2019-01-17 |  3   |
---------------------
```

So as today 17-Jan so i need output till current date. I have tried query but it is not given me 01-Jan to 14-Jan

```
SELECT calendar.datefield, COUNT(calendar.datefield)
FROM calendar
LEFT JOIN final_registration
    ON DATE_FORMAT(calendar.datefield, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT(final_registration.booking_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(calendar.datefield, '%Y-%m-%d') <= DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d' )
  AND DATE_FORMAT(calendar.datefield, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE(), '%Y-%m' )
  AND final_registration.event_id = '101'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(calendar.datefield, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

My query gave me below result:

```
*--------------------*
|  datefield | count |
*--------------------*
| 2019-01-15 |   2   |
| 2019-01-16 |   1   |
| 2019-01-17 |   3   |
*--------------------*
```

I have tried lots but not able to get my result.

Comment: `INNER JOIN` instead `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: Roy's suggestion won't help in this instance. Instead, consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: @Roy i have tried this but the result same. no change.

Comment: @Strawberry can you suggest me any application code? where i can put.

Comment: I don't what application code you're intending to use - although I only know PHP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making your `LEFT` join into an `INNER` join by including criteria in the `WHERE` clause.  Try this:

```
SELECT calendar.datefield, COUNT(calendar.datefield)
FROM calendar
LEFT JOIN final_registration
    ON DATE_FORMAT(calendar.datefield, '%Y-%m-%d') = DATE_FORMAT
(final_registration.booking_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
  AND final_registration.event_id = '101'
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(calendar.datefield, '%Y-%m-%d') <= DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE(), '%Y-%m-%d' )
  AND DATE_FORMAT(calendar.datefield, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE(), '%Y-%m' )
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(calendar.datefield, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Comment: Great, You save my life @richard hansell

Comment: I'm not sure that `COUNT(calendar.datefield)` is correct logic.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move some of the restrictions in the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT
    c.datefield,
    COUNT(f.booking_date) AS cnt
FROM calendar c
LEFT JOIN final_registration f
    ON c.datefield = DATE(f.booking_date) AND
       f.event_id = '101'
WHERE
    c.datefield BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-01') AND CURDATE()
GROUP BY
    c.datefield;
```

[image]

### Demo

Note that you want to count a field from the `final_registration` table, which appears on the right side of the left join.

The delay in my answer was due to cleaning up your query to remove all the unneeded calls to `DATE_FORMAT`.  You should be able to deal directly with the `datefield`.  As for the `WHERE` clause, it seems that you just want dates which are in the current month, but no later than the current day in the month.